# Mysql not accepting user account BUT root@localhost

Tags: php, mysql

My php application can accept the login and password for root@localhost, but when I change it to the DB user, I see

> Access denied for user 'eramba'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

1. mysql user query output
2. first image - database.php settings
3. GRANT for eramba@localhost
   [image]

I had flush privileges after adding the eramba user. I have no anonymous users.

. [image: my database.php settings]
[image: GRANT for eramba@localhost]

I'm lost

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: Try changing password.

Comment: ahhhh I just changed the password to something other than the same value as the login and it worked lol. That was odd. Thank you!